# Чем отличается Entity Framework от LINQ to SQL?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq2sql

Чем отличается Entity Framework от LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Linq2Sql позволяет использовать произвольные типы в свойствах, на которые промаппированы колонки БД, например, перечисления.

Linq2Sql позволяет дописывать сгенерированный код.

Linq2Sql позволяет преобразовать в список объектов результат выполнения произвольного запроса, написанного в виде sql-текста.

EntityFramework позволяет данные для одного класса бизнес-логики помещать в несколько таблиц БД.

EntityFramework имеет расширяемый интерфейс доступа к данным, позволяющий использовать его с разными СУБД.

Comment: Ответ несколько устарел

Comment: Ну, ещё в 2017 году была такая ситуация, что я пользовался Linq2Sql, а мой коллега EntityFramework, потому что Microsoft рекомендуют именно второй инструмент, и в итоге у него всё время были проблемы из-за того, что в EF куча нужного не поддерживается, а у меня в Linq2Sql всё работало. Хотя он типа устарел и не рекомендуется к использованию.

Comment: Тем не менее, сейчас в EF ничто не мешает использовать перечисления, дописывать сгенерированный код и мапить произвольные запросы.

Answer (score -3):

Entity Framework - это [ORM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM) для .net.
LINQ to SQL - библиотека, позволяющая работать с sql субд с помощью linq.

Сам LINQ не ограничивается только "Новой формой написать запрос". С помощью него можно работать с любым поставщиком данных - память, xml,...

Comment: LINQ to SQL тоже ORM. Но поддерживающий только СУБД MS SQL Server и SQL Server CE.